# A couple of problems with instant search and list selection in SVELTE

Tags: javascript, svelte

I have the code below. The EXPECTED behavior is as follows:

1. When the page loads the form field should be in focus.
2. When the user clicks the up/down arrows the items in the list should be selected via a CSS background color change.
3. When the user types into the form field, an "instant search" is applied to the list and only items that match the search appear.
4. If the user types an item that is not in the list and they submit it, the page should automatically update with the list appearing and the new item in the list.

Everything seems to work until step 4. If you try to submit an item to the list the page does not update with the new items and the form loses focus.

I've created this script before with React using ref and useEffect. I am exploring SVELTE to see what a similar script looks like.

Thank you!

**Interactive example:**

https://svelte.dev/repl/a544e3d48d3f46c89249d16c10270f0f?version=3.30.0

```
<script>
    import { onMount } from 'svelte';
    let clients = ["a Little piggy","b little piggy","c little piggy"]; //hard coded api data
    let clientsClone = [...clients];
    let indexVal = -1;
    let downArrowPress = 40;
    let upArrowPress = 38;
    let clientInputTextField = "";
    let selectedClient = "";

     //______________________BEGIN focus input field on page load

     onMount(function() {
        clientInputTextField.focus();
     });

     //_______________________END focus input field on page load.


     // ______________________BEGIN instant search algorithm 
    function instantSearch(query,listArr) {
        let arr = [...listArr]
        let newList = []

       arr.map(val =>{
            query.split(" ").map(word =>{
                if(val.toLowerCase().indexOf(word.toLowerCase()) != -1){
                    newList.push(val)
                }
            })
       })
       
       console.log(newList)
       return newList
    }
    //_________________________END instant search algorithm


    function handleKeydown(event){
        
    
        if(event.keyCode === upArrowPress){
           indexVal-=1;    
           indexVal = indexVal < 0 ?  clients.length : indexVal
           console.log(indexVal);
        }

        if(event.keyCode === downArrowPress){
           indexVal+=1;
           indexVal = indexVal > clients.length ?  0 : indexVal
           console.log(indexVal);
        }

        if(indexVal > clients.length -1 || indexVal < 0){
           clientInputTextField.focus(); 
        }else{
            clientInputTextField.blur()
        }
    
     }

     
     function searchItems(event){
        console.log(event.target.value)
        let result = instantSearch(event.target.value, clients);
        clientsClone = [...result]
        console.log(result)
        
     }


     function handleSubmit(){
  
        console.log(selectedClient)
        clients.push(selectedClient)
        selectedClient = "";


     }




</script>


<svelte:window on:keydown={handleKeydown}/>

<form on:submit|preventDefault={handleSubmit}>
    <input type="text" name=""  on:input={searchItems} bind:this={clientInputTextField} bind:value={selectedClient}>
    <input type="submit" name="">
</form>



<ul>
    {#each clientsClone as client, i}
        {#if i === indexVal}
            <li style="background-color:orange">{client}</li>
            {:else}
            <li style="">{client}</li>
        {/if}
    {/each}
</ul>
```

**EDIT**

The "instant search" is such a mess that I really only have the following code working:

https://svelte.dev/repl/a52d1935209f4cbbb8289b0096374288?version=3.30.0

```
<script>
    import { onMount } from 'svelte';
    let clients = ["a Little piggy","b little piggy","c little piggy"]; 
    let indexVal = -1;
    let downArrowPress = 40;
    let upArrowPress = 38;
    let clientInputTextField = "";



     onMount(function() {
        clientInputTextField.focus();
     });



    function handleKeydown(event){
        
    
        if(event.keyCode === upArrowPress){
           indexVal-=1;    
           indexVal = indexVal < 0 ?  clients.length : indexVal
           console.log(indexVal);
        }

        if(event.keyCode === downArrowPress){
           indexVal+=1;
           indexVal = indexVal > clients.length ?  0 : indexVal
           console.log(indexVal);
        }

        if(indexVal > clients.length -1 || indexVal < 0){
           clientInputTextField.focus(); 
        }else{
            clientInputTextField.blur()
        }
    
     }






</script>


<svelte:window on:keydown={handleKeydown}/>

<form>
    <input type="text" name="" bind:this={clientInputTextField} >
    <input type="submit" name="">
</form>



<ul>
    {#each clients as client, i}
        {#if i === indexVal}
            <li style="background-color:orange">{client}</li>
            {:else}
            <li style="">{client}</li>
        {/if}
    {/each}
</ul>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to attach an event handler to the form that listens for a `submit` event. To get the value of the `input` field, you'll also need to give it a `name` attribute:

```js
<form on:submit|preventDefault={handleSubmit}>
    <input type="text" name="input" bind:this={clientInputTextField} >
    <input type="submit" name="">
</form>
```

Note that the `preventDefault` modifier prevents the page from actually submitting the form (i.e. changing the URL). Depending on your use case, you may not want this behavior.

To then update your list of `clients` you can define a simple `handleSubmit` function like so:

```js
function handleSubmit(e) {
    const value = e.target.input.value;
    clients = [...clients, value]
}
```

After adding this to your edited code the full example looks like this:

```js
<script>
    import { onMount } from 'svelte';
    let clients = ["a Little piggy","b little piggy","c little piggy"]; 
    let indexVal = -1;
    let downArrowPress = 40;
    let upArrowPress = 38;
    let clientInputTextField = "";

    onMount(function() {
        clientInputTextField.focus();
    });

    function handleKeydown(event) {
        if(event.keyCode === upArrowPress) {
            indexVal-=1;    
            indexVal = indexVal < 0 ?  clients.length : indexVal
            console.log(indexVal);
        }

        if(event.keyCode === downArrowPress) {
            indexVal+=1;
            indexVal = indexVal > clients.length ?  0 : indexVal
            console.log(indexVal);
        }

        if(indexVal > clients.length -1 || indexVal < 0){
            clientInputTextField.focus(); 
        } else {
            clientInputTextField.blur()
        }   
    }
    
    function handleSubmit(e) {
        const value = e.target.input.value;
        console.log(value);
        clients = [...clients, value]
    }
</script>

<svelte:window on:keydown={handleKeydown}/>

<form on:submit|preventDefault={handleSubmit}>
    <input type="text" name="input" bind:this={clientInputTextField} >
    <input type="submit" name="">
</form>

<ul>
    {#each clients as client, i}
        {#if i === indexVal}
            <li style="background-color:orange">{client}</li>
            {:else}
            <li style="">{client}</li>
        {/if}
    {/each}
</ul>
```

Comment: Ultimately I am trying to marry this with instant search per the first example.

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/65030010/how-to-marry-this-todo-list-with-instant-search-in-svelte